# PowerShell regex to filter values between {{ and }}

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to write a regex to filter the values, that exist between curly braces:
Example: `$path = C:\serices\ApplicationName\{{NewFolderName}}`

I want to filter the value "NewFolderName" from the above variable. Once I execute, I want to see `"NewFolderName"` in my output. I'm using PowerShell version 2.0. Can someone please suggest me the possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the full powershell for your question.

```
$path = "C:\users\{{XXX}}\Downloads\{{YYY}}\AppName"
$matches = [regex]::Matches($path,"\{{2}(.*?)\}{2}").value
```

Comment: Thank a lot Micheal. This is working fine. Could you please tell me what is mean by `{2}`. Thanks

Comment: @Mahesh, in regular expressions that `{2}` means two repetitions of the previous pattern.   So another way of writing this is `$matches = [regex]::Matches($path,"\{\{(.*?)\}\}").value`.   If Michael's answer helped you, please up-vote it and mark it answered.

Comment: Thanks Burt_Harris

Answer (score 2):

One way would be:

```
\{{2}(.*?)\}{2}
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yR5sN4/1).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I want pull all possible matches from the variable. example: if this is my variable, ``$path = "C:\Users\{{XXX}}\Downloads\{{YYY}}\AppName"``

I want following values in my output:
``XXX`` and ``YYY``